# Can $G$ (Newton's constant) be thought of as a fundamental parameter of physics?

Tags: gravity, physical-constants

Can I think of Newton's Gravitational Constant as a fundamental parameter of nature (based on our current understanding of physics)?

I realize that it is very unlikely that $G$ is actually a fundamental parameter since, among other things, it has units. I am trying to come up with an easy-to-understand example of "a parameter of a model of nature" for laymen.

Can the speed of light be thought of as another "fundamental parameter of physics" for the purpose of this?

Are there any other examples of parameters of a physics model that would be easy to grasp for a non-science audience?

Comment: In our current model, I think you can. Some of the  fundamental parameters are Newton’s constant $G$, speed of light $c$, Planck’s constant $\hbar$, Boltzmann’ constant $k$.

Comment: Plenty of fundamental constants have units. Most, in fact.

Comment: @Gert: Isn't is expected that the theory of everything, or whatever you want to call it (which we don't know), will only have unitless parameters?

Comment: *Plenty of fundamental constants have units.* And so their values have no physical significance. Stick with dimensionless constants if you want physical significance.

Comment: So the speed of light in vacuum $c$, the gravitational constant $G$, the Planck constant $h$, the electric constant $ε_0$, and the elementary charge $e$ have no 'physical significance'?.

Comment: I believe G. Smith is saying that the values have no physical significance. 1 meter is 100 cm. The value depends on the units you choose. But the number 1 is the number 1.

Comment: @Gert Physicists routinely take $c$, $G$, $\hbar$, and $1/4\pi\epsilon_0$ to all be 1. That’s a good indication that their “usual” SI values don’t have physical significance. Their values depend on human-chosen units. By contrast, you can’t take the fine-structure constant to be 1.

Comment: @Gert Is the speed of light “large”? Not in megaparsecs per second.

Comment: There are two kind of fundamental constants, dimensionless and dimensionful, of which G is one. I suggest reading the classic trialouge https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0110060 in which the argument is made for 3, 2 or actually zero dimensionful constants

Answer (score 2):

> Can I think of Newton's Gravitational Constant as a fundamental parameter of nature (based on our current understanding of physics)?

> Can the speed of light be thought of as another "fundamental parameter of physics" for the purpose of this?

No, as surprising as it may seem, neither $c$ nor $G$ are considered fundamental constants simply because they have units. As such, their values don’t tell us about physics but about our units. In fact, this is how the SI units are defined in practice now.

> I am trying to come up with an easy-to-understand example of "a parameter of a model of nature" for laymen.

> Are there any other examples of parameters of a physics model that would be easy to grasp for a non-science majority?

If you want constants whose values tell us about physics rather than units then you need to look at unitless constants. Furthermore, you must exclude constants like $\pi$ whose value can be determined by pure mathematical computation. We need unitless constants whose value can only be determined experimentally. The most “layman friendly” of these is the fine structure constant $\alpha$.

$\alpha$ basically represents the strength of the electromagnetic force in a dimensionless way. $\alpha$ can be written in terms of constants with units as $$\alpha = \frac{k e^2}{c \hbar}$$

Very often when discussing the physical meaning of the constants with units people will talk about what would happen if one of them were doubled. But because of the relationship above it is impossible to change just one of these quantities. So, you must always specify at least two that change. Let’s therefore consider a very simplified example showing the importance of the dimensionless quantity:

In our example we will simply measure the length of a bar of metal in SI meters. The SI meter is based on the Caesium hyperfine transition and $c$. In terms of the quantities above the length of a meter is proportional to $\hbar/c\alpha^4$. Similarly, the length of a bar of metal scales with the Bohr radius so in terms of the quantities above it is proportional to $\hbar/c\alpha$.

So, first suppose that we double $c$ and halve $\hbar$. This will keep $\alpha$ fixed. The length of the meter will go down by a factor of 4, but so will the length of the metal bar. So the length of the metal bar measured in meters will be the same! Doubling $c$ and halving $\hbar$ will have no physical consequences because $\alpha$ was unchanged.

Now, suppose that we again double $c$ but halve $\alpha$. The length of the meter will increase by a factor of 8, but the length of the meter bar will stay the same. So the length of the metal bar measured in meters will go down by a factor of 8. Thus, a change in the unitless $\alpha$ is physically meaningful, while a change in the constants with units were not.

Answer (score 2):

John Baez's article [How Many Fundamental Constants Are There?](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/constants.html) is a pretty good explication of how physicists think about fundamental constants.  It's not quite written at the layman's level, though — more of the "advanced undergraduate" level.

> You might at first think that the speed of light, Planck's constant and Newton's gravitational constant are great examples of fundamental physical constants.
>
> But in fundamental physics, these constants are so important that lots of people use units where they all equal 1! The point is that we can choose units of length, time and mass however we want. That's three independent choices, so with a little luck we can use them to get our favorite three constants to equal 1.
>
> ...
>
> On the other hand, certain constants don't depend on the units we use - these are called "dimensionless" constants. Some of them are numbers like pi, e, and the golden ratio - purely mathematical constants, which anyone with a computer can calculate to as many decimal places as they want. But others - at present - can only be determined by experiment. These tell us facts about nature that are completely independent of our choices of units.
>
> The most famous example is the "fine structure constant", $e^2/\hbar c$. Here $e$ is the electron charge, $\hbar$ is Planck's constant, and $c$ is the speed of light. If you work out the units involved you'll see it's dimensionless, and experiments show that it's about 1/137.03599. Nobody knows why it equals this. At present, it's a completely mysterious raw fact about the universe!
>
> Constants that aren't dimensionless can be regarded as relating one sort of unit to another. For example, the speed of light has units of length over time, so it can be used to turn units of time (like years) into units of length (like light-years), or vice versa. People who are interested in fundamental physical constants usually start by doing this as much as possible - leaving the dimensionless constants, which are the really interesting ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [$G$ is a fundamental constant in physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_constant#Number_of_fundamental_constants). The speed of light is also a fundamental constant, and so is the Planck constant.

Comment: G is **not** a fundamental constant, even when you make a link to an article where it's claimed to be.-10

Answer (score -3):

There are just a few fundamental constants in Nature.. Like a Planck-length, or a Planck-second, a Planck-mass. Then we also have the coupling strength of the four (three, if gravity, which has mass as its source, which I already mentioned, is excluded) forces. More **fundamental** constants are not to be found.

Of course, $G$ (which also enters General Relativity) is constant, like my body temperature is too (under normal circumstances). And also is the speed of light,  $c$. Or Planck's constant, $h$. Or the spring constant $k$. Or whatever constant. But they can all be formed from the **truly** basic constants (units) I mentioned. These units (as the name already suggests) never vary (so they are constant). The non-fundamental constants can vary (in value) because our metric system has quite arbitrary units, like the meter, second, Joule, kilogram, etc. How can they be constants if they can vary?
If we express the non-fundamental constants in the fundamental constants I named, then these constants are the same for every intelligence in the Universe.
This means that all constants, setting the fundamental constants equal to one. Isn't that simple?
Except, of course, for the coupling strengths of the four forces. Obviously they can not all be equal to one.

So, tell laymen that $G$ is not really a fundamental constant. It's a constant, but not made up of fundamentals. And that its true value is one.

Comment: Why the downvote? I can't stand it if no reason is given. I really don't care who you are, if only the reason would be given!!! Otherwise, I think this is done because someone holds a grudge against me.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here.  Not all constants have units (see e.g. the fine structure constant for a fundamental one, or the dielectric susceptibility of water for a non-fundamental one).  No unit is necessarily more fundamental than another (there are conventional SI base units, but this is bookkeeping).  Finally, you mention that all constants can be built out of "truly basic" ones, but then don't actually answer the question, which was whether $G$ should be considered one of them.

Comment: @J.Murray The constants you name are ratios of non-fundamentals. Just numbers. I wrote that non-reducible units are true constants. A Planck-length is a Planck-length is a Planck-length. The same holds for mass, time, and the coupling constants. Concerning your last point, I edited.

Comment: @J.Murray I think you just don't understand.

Comment: I understand, I just completely disagree.  You said that the electromagnetic coupling constant is fundamental, but then said in your comment that it isn't. You think there's something fundamentally special about the Planck length that distinguishes it from the meter, when they're both simply choices of units.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't vote to close a question and then answer that question. Closing a question means it shouldn't be answered, so doing this makes it seem like you think you are the only person who deserves to answer the question.

Comment: *//"You think there's something fundamentally special about the Planck length that distinguishes it from the meter, when they're both simply choices of units."//* -- @J.Murray, i also think that.  and so do the aliens on the planet Zog.  The Planck length is a standard that both the Zoglings and Earthlings can use in common as a reference.  That is not the case with the meter.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson The Planck length is a quantity obtained via dimensional analysis, using constants like $G$ which, by alternate choice of convention, could be scaled by essentially arbitrary numerical factors (e.g. why not write $G$ as $1/4\pi\epsilon_G$ in analogy with electromagnetism? Why not use $h$ instead of $\hbar$?).  It may represent a scale at which we would expect the onset of quantum gravity effects, but that doesn't mean that what we call a Planck length has any special or unique significance which would justify labeling it as a fundamental constant of nature.

Comment: @J.Murray, i am well aware of how the Planck length or any other Planck unit is derived.  And it **well** has significance over any of the anthropometric units like the foot or meter.  The Zoglings know what a Planck length is, but they don't know what a meter is.  Also, my preference has always been that the Planck units normalize $c$, $\hbar$, $4 \pi G$, and $\epsilon_0$ (the *"rationalized"* Planck units).  It doesn't change the scale by much, but if I were a Zogling, that's what I would use.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Zoglings would also agree on the Bohr radius and the lattice constant of gold, but that's not a good reason to elevate any of those things to the level of a fundamental constant of nature as advocated in this answer.  In any case, this is not a conversation which is suitable for a comment thread on somebody else's answer.

Comment: @J.Murray the reason that the Bohr radius is not on the list of most natural units is because it depends on parameters of specific particles that would have to be agreed upon in common.  Planck units do not reference **any** object or particle as a prototype object to base measurement of physical quantity on.

Comment: if [rationalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units) [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Alternative_choices_of_normalization) are used, then the Zogians and us both know that the speed of propagation and the characteristic impedance of both [EM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) and [GEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) waves are both equal to 1.